# remove one class when animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to animate menu-panel. It should slide to the left. But it doesn't work right. And I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the current code (e.g. you were missing a `.` on one panel selector and not referencing `panel1` after changing the panel class. I also switched to absolute positioning with the arrow inside the panel.

I did a little cleanup to make the changes obvious (you should not repeat jQuery selectors - use temp vars instead):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/2x3uT/8/

```
$(function () {
    $('.slider-arrow').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $panel = $(".panel, .panel1");
        var left = -53;
        var text = '&raquo;';
        if ($this.hasClass('hide')) {
            text = '&laquo;';
            left = 0;
        }
        $panel.animate({
            left: left
        }, 700, function () {
            // Animation complete.
            $this.html(text).toggleClass('hide').toggleClass('show');
            $panel.toggleClass('panel').toggleClass('panel1');
        });
    });

});
```

*You can tweak the position numbers to make it match what you wanted.*